# Timing of Slayer Studying Target after/during Sneak Attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, sneak-attack, immediate-actions

I find this statement from the slayer's [Studied Target](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer#TOC-Studied-Target-Ex-) ability confusing:

> If a slayer deals sneak attack damage to a target, he can study that
>   target as an immediate action, allowing him to apply his studied
>   target bonuses against that target (including to the normal weapon
>   damage roll).

Does this mean:

1. If a slayer **succeeds** on a sneak attack roll against a foe, that the Studied Target bonus will be added to the damage roll for that sneak attack
2. If a slayer **attempts** a sneak attack against a foe, that the Studied Target bonus will be added to the attack roll and damage roll for that sneak attack
3. If a slayer **completes** a sneak attack against a foe, that the Studied Target bonus will come into effect after the damage roll for that sneak attack

I presume the first to be most likely, since it mentions damage roll in parentheses, but the first line requires damage to be dealt.

I am mostly confused by the meaning of the terminology "normal weapon damage roll" - I was under the impression a Sneak Attack is not considered a normal damage roll, or that a weapon was required to perform one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slayer that deals a creature sneak attack damage can take an immediate action to employ his extraordinary ability studied target to gain the slayer's studied target bonus against his foe *in addition* to any damage already dealt.

What the game means when it sometimes refers to *making a sneak attack* is *dealing sneak attack damage*, and when a creature's dealt sneak attack damage, the creature's made a sneak attack. Sneak attack damage is dealt *automatically* upon the creature or its foe meeting certain conditions, and the extra dice are added to the attack's damage. *Attempting* a sneak attack isn't really a thing, and a creature *succeeds on* or *completes* a sneak attack when it sums the sneak attack damage and applies it to the foe!

Sneak attack damage *is* [precision damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Sneak-Attack), so there are some limits on it, but it *is* otherwise normal damage, and a weapon isn't always required to perform it—unarmed strikes, natural weapons, and some spells are capable of dealing sneak attack damage.

Comment: For a more in-depth discussion on the use of *make a sneak attack **versus** deal sneak attack damage* in *3.5e*, see [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/91668/8610).